# Machine unable to connect to private IP (though able to connect to public IP)

Tags: networking, server, ufw

I have an Ubuntu machine, which has two NICs, one configured with a public IP address, and the other configured in a private IP range (10.2.0.0).

Other machines are able to ping the machine on both addresses, but the machine itself cannot ping other machines on the private network.

### Any idea what should I check (besides the below data) to debug the issue?

**Machine's data (edited):**

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntumachine 4.4.0-83-generic #106-Ubuntu SMP Mon lll kk 17:54:43 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ ifconfig -a
ensX      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr cc:dd:00:ee:2f:22
          inet addr:216.245.aaa.bbb  Bcast:216.245.aaa.159  Mask:255.255.255.248
          inet6 addr: XXXX::YYYY:ff:fe97:2f22/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:28695 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29577 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3793406 (3.7 MB)  TX bytes:4828424 (4.8 MB)

ensY     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr gg:hh:00:ii:2f:22
          inet addr:10.2.0.1  Bcast:10.2.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: ZZZZ::WWWW:ff:feee:d402/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:103 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1302 (1.3 KB)  TX bytes:5310 (5.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:797 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:797 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:66kk8 (66.2 KB)  TX bytes:66kk8 (66.2 KB)

$ netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         216.245.aaa.153 0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ensX
10.2.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ensY
216.245.aaa.152 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U         0 0          0 ensX

$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         153-aaa-245-216 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ensX
10.2.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ensY
localnet        *               255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 ensX

$ sudo lshw -c network
[sudo] password for ronbarak:
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Virtio network device
       vendor: Red Hat, Inc
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
       logical name: ensX
       version: 00
       serial: cc:dd:00:ee:2f:22
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msix bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=virtio_net driverversion=1.0.0 ip=216.245.aaa.bbb latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes
       resources: irq:11 ioport:c060(size=32) memory:fc092000-fc092fff memory:fc000000-fc03ffff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Virtio network device
       vendor: Red Hat, Inc
       physical id: 4
       bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
       logical name: ensY
       version: 00
       serial: gg:hh:00:ii:2f:22
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msix bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=virtio_net driverversion=1.0.0 ip=10.2.0.1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes
       resources: irq:11 ioport:c080(size=32) memory:fc093000-fc093fff memory:fc040000-fc07ffff

$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ensX
iface ensX inet static
        address 216.245.aaa.bbb
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        network 216.245.aaa.152
        broadcast 216.245.aaa.159
        gateway 216.245.aaa.153
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 208.aaa.bbb.242 208.aaa.bbb.250
        dns-search nimhq.net

# Internal interface
auto ensY
iface ensYinet static
  address 10.2.0.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0

$ service ufw status
? ufw.service - Uncomplicated firewall
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ufw.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2017-07-01 19:09:05 ZAST; 5h 29min ago
  Process: 364 ExecStart=/lib/ufw/ufw-init start quiet (code=exited, status=0/
 Main PID: 364 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/ufw.service

$ cat /etc/default/ufw
# /etc/default/ufw
#

# Set to yes to apply rules to support IPv6 (no means only IPv6 on loopback
# accepted). You will need to 'disable' and then 'enable' the firewall for
# the changes to take affect.
IPV6=yes

# Set the default input policy to ACCEPT, DROP, or REJECT. Please note that if
# you change this you will most likely want to adjust your rules.
DEFAULT_INPUT_POLICY="DROP"

# Set the default output policy to ACCEPT, DROP, or REJECT. Please note that if
# you change this you will most likely want to adjust your rules.
DEFAULT_OUTPUT_POLICY="ACCEPT"

# Set the default forward policy to ACCEPT, DROP or REJECT.  Please note that
# if you change this you will most likely want to adjust your rules
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="DROP"

# Set the default application policy to ACCEPT, DROP, REJECT or SKIP. Please
# note that setting this to ACCEPT may be a security risk. See 'man ufw' for
# details
DEFAULT_APPLICATION_POLICY="SKIP"

# By default, ufw only touches its own chains. Set this to 'yes' to have ufw
# manage the built-in chains too. Warning: setting this to 'yes' will break
# non-ufw managed firewall rules
MANAGE_BUILTINS=no

#
# IPT backend
#
# only enable if using iptables backend
IPT_SYSCTL=/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf

# Extra connection tracking modules to load. Complete list can be found in
# net/netfilter/Kconfig of your kernel source. Some common modules:
# nf_conntrack_irc, nf_nat_irc: DCC (Direct Client to Client) support
# nf_conntrack_netbios_ns: NetBIOS (samba) client support
# nf_conntrack_pptp, nf_nat_pptp: PPTP over stateful firewall/NAT
# nf_conntrack_ftp, nf_nat_ftp: active FTP support
# nf_conntrack_tftp, nf_nat_tftp: TFTP support (server side)
IPT_MODULES="nf_conntrack_ftp nf_nat_ftp nf_conntrack_netbios_ns"

$ cat /etc/ufw/sysctl.conf
#
# Configuration file for setting network variables. Please note these settings
# override /etc/sysctl.conf. If you prefer to use /etc/sysctl.conf, please
# adjust IPT_SYSCTL in /etc/default/ufw.
#

# Uncomment this to allow this host to route packets between interfaces
#net/ipv4/ip_forward=1
#net/ipv6/conf/default/forwarding=1
#net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding=1

# Turn on Source Address Verification in all interfaces to prevent some
# spoofing attacks
net/ipv4/conf/default/rp_filter=1
net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter=1

# Do not accept IP source route packets (we are not a router)
net/ipv4/conf/default/accept_source_route=0
net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_source_route=0
net/ipv6/conf/default/accept_source_route=0
net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_source_route=0

# Disable ICMP redirects. ICMP redirects are rarely used but can be used in
# MITM (man-in-the-middle) attacks. Disabling ICMP may disrupt legitimate
# traffic to those sites.
net/ipv4/conf/default/accept_redirects=0
net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_redirects=0
net/ipv6/conf/default/accept_redirects=0
net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_redirects=0

# Ignore bogus ICMP errors
net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts=1
net/ipv4/icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses=1
net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all=0

# Don't log Martian Packets (impossible packets)
net/ipv4/conf/default/log_martians=0
net/ipv4/conf/all/log_martians=0

# Change to '1' to enable TCP/IP SYN cookies This disables TCP Window Scaling
# (http://lkml.org/lkml/2008/2/5/167)
net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies=0

#net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout=30
#net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl=1800

# normally allowing tcp_sack is ok, but if going through OpenBSD 3.8 RELEASE or
# earlier pf firewall, should set this to 0
net/ipv4/tcp_sack=1

# Uncomment this to turn off ipv6 autoconfiguration
#net/ipv6/conf/default/autoconf=0
#net/ipv6/conf/all/autoconf=0

# Uncomment this to enable ipv6 privacy addressing
#net/ipv6/conf/default/use_tempaddr=2
#net/ipv6/conf/all/use_tempaddr=2

$ sudo service network-manager  status
? network-manager.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

$ grep -ve "^#" /etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses = 1
```

Comment: I'm going to assume that the same box which CAN ping Ubuntu is the same box which CANNOT be pinged by Ubuntu and that the one way working / not working is consistent. The fact you get echo responses (the ping can find it's way back when you ping the Ubuntu box) means there's almost certainly not an addressing or routing issue. Really looks like the firewall is up on the internal box you've mentioned - is it a Windows machine?

Comment: @AJRossington,The machines on the private network are *nix: Ubuntu and OSX.

Comment: And can those machines ping each other?

Comment: @AJRossington, yes.

Comment: I'd be unplugging the WAN port and retrying pings. Also, if you traceroute from this box to each internal host, does it show itself going out of the internal interface or external? If you're running a gui, I'd also install wireshark and monitor the interfaces, see if you can see traffic going out and back in.

Comment: Also - just to check. The machines you can't ping are in the same subnet with same netmask as the ubuntu box? They're not being natted by another box / router before they get to 10.2.0.0? Could to do a traceroute to 8.8.8.8 from one of the internal hosts and post the output? Be worth blanking out your public ip though

Comment: Re "The machines you can't ping are in the same subnet with same netmask as the ubuntu box?", @AJRossington, that's a very good suggestion: thanks. I'll try the traceroute as soon as I get a time window - in which I can play with the public IP addresses - and report back.